# How to overload C++ operator, but for only certain inputs?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class for which I would like to overload the addition operators. For my use case, it makes sense only to allow addition in the case where the `a` variable of each object is equal.

What is the best way to handle the case where they are not? Throw an exception, something else?

```
class A {
private:
    int a, b;

public:
    A(int a, int b)
        :a(a), b(b) {}

    A& operator+=(const A& rhs) {
        if (this->a == rhs.a) {
            this->b += rhs.b;
            return *this;
        }
        else { //this->a != rhs.a
            //what should I put here?
        }
    }
};
```

.

Edits:

These objects are created at run-time during file io.

These objects represent a data point in a spectrum. It only makes sense to add the intensities of two data points if they are at the same position.

`a` is limited to the range (-180.0, 360.0)

Comment: It probably makes sense to throw in such case, since it seems like it is a responsibility of a user of the class to pass correct types to the operator.

Comment: Throw exception, or change the use case.

Comment: How about let `a` become a template variable? Then it could be checked in compile time. Also this use case is not straightforward. Why should `+=` work only under certain states?

Comment: Ideally, illegal states should be unrepresentable. In your case, `a` probably could be a template parameter rather than a member variable.

Comment: Does the `a` value have a restricted range?

Comment: "These objects represent a data point in a spectrum. It only makes sense to add the intensities of two data points if they are at the same position." Would it make sense to sort your date first, possibly bin it and only then perform the operations?

Answer (score 1):

This smells like `a` is the property of the type, not a property of the value... What exactly does this class represent?

The minimally viable (IMHO) way to approach this is to make explicit the transition from an "anything goes" type to a "type compatible with a particular value of a". I.e.:

```
MyClass x(1,2), y(1,5);

x += y; // won't compile

x.makeCompatibleWith(y) += y; // will compile
```

It's usually a pessimization to have arithmetic operators like `+=` throw. Instead, have something else assume the cost - then the cost is explicit, and you can keep `+=` nothrow. It's also easy to search the project for costly operations (well, `makeCompatibleWith` is not super expensive, just more expensive than `+=` since it adds the overhead of exception handling).

Assuming that the invalid cases are meant to be caught in testing, the `makeCompatibleWith` function could `assert` the condition it requires, but in release builds it would return some dummy object that turns the `+=` into a no-op since it won't modify `x` - while still keeping `+=` very simple and quick.

As to what exactly should `makeCompatibleWith` return: it's up to you. It can be a type that carries a reference, for example:

```
class MyClass
{
  int a, b;
  struct Internal
  {
    MyClass &val;
    Internal(MyClass &val) : val(val) {}
    MyClass &operator+=(const MyClass &o) noexcept {
      val.b += o.b;
      return val;
    }
    MyClass operator+(const MyClass &o) const noexcept {
      return { val.a, val.b + o.b };
    }
  };
public:
  MyClass() : a{}, b{} {}
  MyClass(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
  Internal makeCompatibleWith(const MyClass &o) noexcept {
    thread_local static MyClass dummy;
    assert(a == o.a);
    if (a != o.a)
      return { dummy };
    return { *this };
  }
};
```

Note that `makeCompatibleWith` would be undefined behavior when used from multiple threads if `dummy` wasn't thread-local.

Comment: These objects represent a data point in a spectrum. It only makes sense to add the intensities of two data points if they are at the same position.

Comment: "It's usually a pessimization..." I think I agree. I may write a container for these which takes care of the equality issues, leaving users dealing with the container, and not the individual elements...

Comment: *It only makes sense to add the intensities of two data points if they are at the same position.* Then the assert + test coverage is the way to go IMHO. At least it's easy to audit such use.

Comment: Another approach would be to not let the user add data points directly, and let the operator that adds spectra do the job. That way things like averages would not be error prone - and, if somehow the spectra have slightly different wavelength coverage, the addition would always provide a union. Or, a dedicated averaging operator could add a property to the data points that would accumulate how many averages were taken for a given point. Etc. But this is so application-specific that it's easy to come up with silly scenarios that never get used - so it's best not to over-engineer this stuff.

Comment: Yeah. I think the container will be exposed to the user, with the individual datapoints being used in the background. I can throw exceptions willy-nilly, and handle them all to make the container noexcept